# Galois cohomology with coefficients in the unit group of a cyclotomic field

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, group-cohomology, galois-cohomology, cyclotomic-fields

While understanding Fermat's last theorem's proof for regular primes, I bumped into a proposition ([http://www2.biglobe.ne.jp/~optimist/algebra/fermat2_proof.html#proof10](http://www2.biglobe.ne.jp/%7Eoptimist/algebra/fermat2_proof.html#proof10), written in Japanese) stating:

> Let $\epsilon$ be a unit of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ and $\tilde\epsilon$ be the complex conjugate of $\epsilon$. Then there exists $r \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\epsilon = \zeta^r \tilde\epsilon$.

Here $p$ is a rational prime and $\zeta$ is a primitive $p$-th root of unity. We denote by $K$ the field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta + \zeta^{-1})$, by $L$ the field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, by $G_r$ the Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ and by $U_K$ (resp. $U_L$) the unit group of $K$ (resp. $L$). It follows that the cohomology group $H^1(G_r, U)$ is isomorphic to $\{ \pm 1 \}$ because $G_r$ is a cyclic group generated by the complex conjugate map $\tilde{}$ and we have $Z^1(G_r, U_L) \simeq \{ z \in U_L \colon z\tilde z = 1 \} = \langle -1, \zeta \rangle$ and $B^1(G_r, U_L) \simeq \{ z / \tilde z \colon z \in U_L \} = \langle \zeta \rangle$. This $H^1(G_r, U_L)$ happens to be isomorphic to $G_r$. The 0-th Tate cohomology group $\widehat H^0(G_r, U_L) = U_K/N_{L/K}(U_L)$ also looks isomorphic to $\{ \pm 1 \}$, although my calculation may be wrong.

My question is, can we generalize this situation? I feel this might be somehow related to class field theory because in class field theory some cohomological computations are employed. However, I don't know much about class field theory. Besides, because we have $H^1(G_r, L^\times) = \{1\}$ from Hilbert 90, I wonder there is a relationship between that and $H^1(G_r, U_L)$.

The question [What is known about first cohomology of the units in a number field?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103345/what-is-known-about-first-cohomology-of-the-units-in-a-number-field) looks somewhat related to my question, but I'm not sure if its answers cover my question.